# Dynamically read images and know its file name

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have react-native with quite some images which I need to show

The images are in `assets/images` folder

No of the images is so much that I can't write an import statement for each one of them.

I also understand we shouldn't add so many images to our project as it would increase app size and should fetch on runtime.

Ignoring all this, I want to import all these images on runtime.

Can someone please help me in figuring out How can I do it? I also need an image file name.

[image: f]

Comment: What tutorial are you following? It’s not clear what you’re trying to do. Are you using the media Asset manager in Xcode?